# Find $ sign preceding by number in string?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, string

An HTML is stored in a `string`, and I have to find `$` (Doller sign) preceded by numeric or space. So as to convert that amount to Euros, then bind that HTML to the page.

> Example: $ 1,230 => € 1,072.97

**NOTE**: HTML may contain JQuery code, which has $ sign for functions, I don't want them to convert.

After finding numbers, conversion is no issue for me.

What I have tried:

```
string strMoney = Regex.Replace(strHtml, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", string.Empty);
```

It's not full proof! How to find such string in HTML using C#?

Comment: You should try to get a functioning regex before turning to SO for help. (Your current regex matches anything but an alphanumeric sequence, including whitespace.)

Also, you shouldn't store data in the HTML. If you need to store data, make a template, which holds the design and client side logic and fill it with data when a request is made.

Comment: It's not data, just a static HTML with some prices.

Comment: @JosefHoppe, there are cases where HTML comes from crawling 3rd party websites

Comment: @Vikrant, can you please post an example of HTML string that includes jQuery code?

Comment: Your regex only keeps alphanumeric characters. It is not keeping other characters, **including the dollar sign and decimal points**. So it stands to reason that you can't find a dollar sign afterwards, since you specifically asked to remove them with your regex.

Comment: Any other solutions are most welcomed